# Eloquent one-to-one relationship, in which model should be the hasOne?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a context where a user can do registrations in conferences. And the registrations can be free or paid depending on the ticket types selected by the user that did the registration.

Doubt 1: But so there should be a 1 to 1 relationship between Registration and Payment. My doubt is if the "hasOne" should be in the Registration model or in the Payment model? Or it is the same? And where is necessary to add the fk? In the the create_payments_table or "create_registrations_table", or both?

Doubt 2: Also, there are 2 payment methods available, credit card or references. In the case of references is necessary to store the generated references in the references table. So there should also exist a 1 to 1 relationship between Payment and Reference. But I have the same doubt where the hasOne should be? In the Payment or in the Reference model?  And where is necessary to add the fk? In the the create_payments_table or "create_references_table", or both?

Doubt 1 models:

```
// Registration Model
class Registration extends Model
    public function payment()
        {
            return $this->hasOne('App\Payment');
        }
    }

// Payment model
class Payment extends Model
{
    public function registration()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Registration');
    }
}
```

Doubt 2 models:

```
// Payment model
class Payment extends Model
{
    public function registration()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Registration');
    }

    public function reference()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Reference');
    }
}
// Reference model
class Reference extends Model
{
    public function payment()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Payment');
    }
}
```

Comment: If registration table has one to one relationship with payment table then payment table requires registration_id as a foreign key. Registration model will have hasOne and Payment model will have belongsTo method.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain why needs to be like that?

Comment: They have followed this convention that's why they have mentioned this thing in their documentation. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

Comment: If you have payment_id on registration then registration belongs to payment. Likewise for reference and payment. If payment has reference_id then payment belongs to reference. But i'm not sure about has one in your cases. It seems has many is more appropriate for your cases.

Comment: Thanks, but its equal to have the payment_id on the registration table or registration_id in the payment table? And then the hasOne depends on that? And can you explain why is hasMany more appropriate? Because a registration has associated one payment and one payment is associated to one registration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel uses a convention that, when understood, may help clarify your structure:

**hasX** relationships (`hasOne`, `hasMany`, `hasManyThrough`, etc.) mean the foreign key is on the **child/outside** relationship.

A `User` has one `Phone`. The User table has no knowledge of a phone. The Phone table has a `user_id` column.

**belongsTo** relationship means the **current** table has the foreign key referencing another table.

A `Phone` belongs to a `User`.

Your "Doubt 1" model code would work well, and is what I'd suggest using. You would place a `registration_id` foreign key in your `payments` table. This ensures that a Payment always references a specific Registration (no orphan payments that you're not sure what were for), and since a Registration might not even have a payment, you aren't left with an empty value that you aren't sure is correct.

As for "Doubt 2" and References, it depends™️ if a Reference is always unique to a Payment, or if one Reference can be used on multiple payments.

If each Payment will have a unique Reference only used once, then the same relationship can be applied. `payment_id` foreign key would be added to Reference table/model, Payment has one Reference, and Reference belongs to Payment.

If a Reference can be applied to more than one Payment, then the `payments` table would need a `reference_id` column. Payment belongs to Reference, and Reference has many Payment.

Hope that helps! Happy programming. :)

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation! Can you explain better this part "...and since a Registration might not even have a payment, you aren't left with an empty value that you aren't sure is correct."?

Comment: Of course! If Registration has a `payment_id` column and there is no payment needed (e.g. free registration), then I assume you'd leave `payment_id` null. This is totally fine, it just might present an opportunity where someone looking at your database _expects_ a payment because the column is there. It's not a critical thing, just a small added benefit of not using that option (in my opinion!).